# StartActivity from a method

Tags: java, android, android-intent

This is more of a Java question as it relates to Android.

My code includes a switch statement with 30 cases. The body of each case has the same format to start an intent relating to that case. I was trying to code the body as a method with the name of the class as an argument, but that code does not compile as the class name has to be hard coded in the intent.

Below is a section of the switch (the long way)

```
            switch(mState) {
    case 0:
               Intent myIntent = new Intent();
               myIntent.setClass(Home_ASM.this, Home_AS0.class);
               startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
               break;

    case 1:
              Intent myIntent1 = new Intent(); 
              myIntent1.setClass(Home_ASM.this, Home_AS1.class);
              startActivityForResult(myIntent1, 2);
              break;
```

and I would like to code such:

```
            switch(mState) {
            case 0:
               myStart(Home_AS0.class,1);
               break;
            case 1:
               myStart(Home_AS1.class,2);
               break;
```

and the method

```
private void myStart(String state, int value) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent();
            myIntent.setClass(Home_ASM.this, state);
            startAcivityForResult(myIntent, value);
            }
```

Any ideas on how I can make this work?

Comment: Can't you change myStart to accept a Class and an Int?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We do a similar thing. our code looks a bit like this:

Switch Statement:

```
case 0:
      {
         launchActivity(ActivityOne.class, value);
         break;
      }
```

Method to launch activity:

```
private void launchActivity(Class<?> aClass, int value) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setClass(this, aClass);
        startActivityForResult(intent, value);
    }
```

You can easily adapt this to take your specific `int` value. Hope this helps!

Comment: Duh, I should have thought about passing the name as a class and not as a string. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Why not have a method

```
private void myStart(Class class, int value)
```

And just pass it a class instead of a string?

Comment: Duh, I should have thought about passing the name as a class and not as a string. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You may try `Class.forName("nameofClass");`

EDIT: After edits, Jon Taylor answer is more appropriate than my answer.
See: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName%28java.lang.String%29

Comment: It's super ugly but looks like what you want...

* ugly because it's a maintenance hell and will break as soon as you refactor a single class or package

Comment: I think this is quite nice, although doesn't he want to just change the method signature to accept a Class rather than a String? or am I missing something?

Comment: @arikg ok so at the risk of sounding stupid, why is my answer not the solution, since he clearly states he wants to call `myStart(Home_AS0.class,1);` with a class passed?  I agree that this is a solution however I am failing to understand (probably because I have made some mistake) as to why this is better than a solution which does exactly what he wanted?

Comment: looking at the edited question I actually support using @JonTaylor code now. no need to use reflection in this case....

Comment: @arikg ah ok :) I hadn't realised the question has been edited lol.